# Best way to avoid circular imports in class methods?

Tags: python, import, circular-dependency, class-method

This is a slightly fairly specific example of the common circular import problem.
I (think I) know all of the common answers to the generic problem, so I was wondering what would be the best practice in the following example.

Suppose we have a module (lets call it *shape.py*) containing a number of related classes. For example, a `Point`, `Line` and `Polygon` class.

Each of these classes has a class method which returns an instance of the class by populating it with data from a file.

The logical (?) layout would be to put the classes and methods for reading the data and populating the class in another module. Lets call it *reader.py*. This presents the problem that *shape.py* needs to import *reader.py* to access the read routines and *reader.py* needs to import *shape.py* in order to instantiate the classes.

The obvious solution is to put the contents of *reader.py* in *shape.py*. But we don't really want to do that as it is not a very clear layout and our *reader.py* and *shape.py* modules are already quite long.

The solution I have seen in many existing packages is to use local imports inside the class methods. This seems a bit clunky and fragile, and in many threads I've seen on stackoverflow it seems to be thought of as a cop-out instead of proper refactoring.

So, is there a better solution?